# Problemas con AJAX para mostrar resultado de consulta de DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.cargando').hide();
 });
 function buscar_datos() {
     subcredito = $("#subcredito").val();
     var parametros = {
     "busqueda": "1",
     "subcredito" : subcredito
 };
 $.ajax({
   data: parametros,
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'ajax.php',
   type: 'post',
   beforeSend: function() {
       $('.cargando').fadeIn(650);
       $(".formulario").hide();
   },
   error: function() {
       console.log("Error")
   },
   complete: function() {
       $(".cargando").fadeOut(1200);
       $('.formulario').fadeIn(3500);
   },
   success: function(valores) {
       $("#subcredito").val("");
       if(valores.existe == "1") {
           $("#num_subcredito").val(valores.subcredito);
           $("#titular").val(valores.cliente);
           $("#producto").val(valores.producto);
           if(valores.grupo){
               $("#grupo").val(valores.grupo);
           } else {
               $("#grupo").val("SIN GRUPO");
           }
           $("#bucket").val(valores.bucket);
       } else {
           console.log("No encontramos nada")
       }
     }
  }) 
}
</script>
```

Mi problema o duda de como resolver es:
Al momento de consultar todo funciona muestra en los inputs los valores de valores.consulta (por asi decirlo) pero por ejemplo si consulta una dato (cuenta) en la base de datos y este no existe, si me notifica con sweet alert o un alert el que no esa cuenta no existe pero carga y muestra en los inputos los resultados de valores.consulta de la ultima consulta verdadera.
Es decir me regresa un resource 0 y me notifica que no existe pero me muestra en pantalla los datos del ultimo resource 1 aun que mi consulta no existe¿No se si me explique?

Lo que pensaba hacer es poner dentro el else al final los valores de los inputs como vacios, pero como ultima opcion a la logica del codigo

Comment: *Lo que pensaba hacer es poner dentro el else al final los valores de los inputs como vacios, pero como ultima opcion a la logica del codigo*. Eso es precisamente lo que tienes que hacer, ¿por qué no lo haces o lo consideras la *última opción*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ponerlo dentro de un formulario y cada vez que se ejecute la petición ajax reinicias el formulario:

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

También puedes añadirle el mismo nombre de clase a las etiquetas que quieres reiniciar

```
$('.delete').val('');
```

Añado que en esta parte del código:

```
  if(valores.grupo){
               $("#grupo").val(valores.grupo);
           } else {
               $("#grupo").val("SIN GRUPO");
           }
```

Lo puedes substituir por lo siguiente:

```
valores.grupo = valores.grupo || "No tiene grupo";
```

Comment: Tu primera opción del .trigger() ¿Dónde la colocaría?

Comment: @Minor tienes que ponerlo en el formulario "<form></form>"

Answer (score 0):

Antes de la función AJAX, limpie los inputs con JQUERY colocandolos de la siguiente manera

```
$("#num_subcredito").val("");
$("#titular").val("");
$("#producto").val("");
$("#grupo").val("");
$("#bucket").val("");
```